# DDMS not working in eclipse

Tags: android, file, ddms

I had sdk 2.2 previously.Then i installed android sdk 2.3 but later uninstalled it.But now the DDMS perspective view file explorer is not working.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using DDMS from within eclipse or independently?

Answer (score 1):

Your Android SDK setting from the eclipse preferences might have been reset.
Change it from:

```
Window-> Preferences->Android->SDK Location
```